# How can I run newer Unity games on OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: macos, crash, games

Most games built with Unity 2018 and Unity 2019 do not work on Mac OS X 10.9. They will launch initially, and occasionally even get as far as the main menu, but invariably crash before entering gameplay.

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _getattrlistbulk
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/Sayonara Wild Hearts.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/UnityPlayer.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

[image: Problem Report Screenshot]

How can I run these games without updating to an ugly flat version of OS X?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120310/discussion-on-question-by-wowfunhappy-how-can-i-run-newer-unity-games-on-os-x-10).

Comment: The underlying reason is most likely that the newer versions of Unity are compiled with newer versions of Xcode which only targets newer versions of OS X.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I would have thought, though, that if 10.10 was the minimum deployment target, it would have taken a lot more than stubbing one method to get games to run.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Depends on how many methods the Unity programmers actually use.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The crash log indicates that the game is looking for a function called `getattrlistbulk`. Because this function doesn't exist in Mavericks, the game doesn't know what to do, and crashes. Ergo, in order for the game to run, we'll have to give it what it wants—a copy of the `getattrlistbulk` function.

(In other words, we need to write some code. Make sure you have Apple's Xcode Command Line Tools installed!)

[getattrlistbulk](https://www.manpagez.com/man/2/getattrlistbulk/) is a [part of the kernel](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.1.97/bsd/vfs/vfs_attrlist.c.auto.html), and I don't understand what it does. But, what if I didn't have to—what if Unity games don't actually need `getattrlistbulk` for anything important? If that were the case, it might be that `getattrlistbulk` wouldn't need to actually *do* anything for a game to run, the function would merely need to *exist*.

Only one way to find out! Let's give this code a try:

```
#include <sys/attr.h>

int getattrlistbulk(int dirfd, struct attrlist * attrList, void * attrBuf, size_t attrBufSize, uint64_t options) {
    return 0;
}
```

This copy of `getattrlistbulk` will always return `0`, no matter what.

If you save this code as `UnityMavericksWorkarounds.m`, you can compile it with:

```
clang -compatibility_version 9999 -o UnityMavericksWorkarounds.dylib -dynamiclib UnityMavericksWorkarounds.m
```

Now, we need to make the game load our new UnityMavericksWorkarounds library. This should be easy to do with the `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` environment variable. Run in the Terminal:

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=UnityMavericksWorkarounds.dylib Sayonara\ Wild\ Hearts.app/Contents/MacOS/Sayonara\ Wild\ Hearts
```

...and watch the game crash the exact same way it did before:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _getattrlistbulk
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/Sayonara Wild Hearts.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/UnityPlayer.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Why can't `UnityPlayer.dylib` find our fancy new `getattrlistbulk` function?

Let's look at the crash report again. UnityPlayer isn't expecting `getattrlistbulk` to be just anywhere, it's expecting it to be in `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`, and so isn't looking inside of our UnityMavericksWorkarounds library. This is due to a concept called two-level namespaces, which you can read more about [here](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/TwoLevelNamespaces.html). And, although two-level namespacing can be turned off via `DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1`, Unity games won't work without it.

Let's try something else. What if we made the game load our library, `UnityMavericksWorkarounds.dylib`, in place of `libSystem.B.dylib`? Apple's `install_name_tool` command makes this easy! Copy UnityMavericksWorkarounds.dylib into the application bundle's `Contents/Frameworks` directory, and then run:

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/UnityMavericksWorkarounds.dylib Sayonara\ Wild\ Hearts.app/Contents/Frameworks/UnityPlayer.dylib
```

(Replace `Sayonara\ Wild\ Hearts` with the name of your game.)

Now, try launching the game again, and...

```
Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: dyld_stub_binder
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/Sayonara Wild Hearts.app/Contents/MacOS/Sayonara Wild Hearts
  Expected in: /Users/USER/Desktop/Sayonara Wild Hearts.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/UnityMavericksWorkarounds.dylib
 in /Users/USER/Desktop/Sayonara Wild Hearts.app/Contents/MacOS/Sayonara Wild Hearts
```

Hey, at least the crash log changed this time! You can probably guess why this didn't work. `libSystem.B.dylib` is an essential system library which contains contains many, many functions. UnityMavericksWorkarounds only contains `getattrlistbulk`. And so although the game now has access to `getattrlistbulk`, it's missing everything else!

What we want is for our UnityMavericksWorkarounds library to also provide all of the other libSystem functions in addition to its own. We can do this by making `libSystem.B.dylib` a [sub-library](http://blog.darlinghq.org/2018/07/mach-o-linking-and-loading-tricks.html) of our `UnityMavericksWorkarounds.dylib`.

I did this using [optool](https://github.com/alexzielenski/optool):

```
optool install -c reexport -p /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib -t Sayonara\ Wild\ Hearts.app/Contents/Frameworks/UnityMavericksWorkarounds.dylib
```

(There's probably a cleaner way to link this at compile-time, but I couldn't figure out how, and optool worked.)

Now, try launching the game again, and...

[image: It works!]

---

## Theoretical FAQs

(Follow-up questions no one has asked, but which they theoretically could.)

#### Q: Is the return value of `0` important?

**A**: Yes. I originally tried `1`, but that caused some games to allocate all available memory and crash once none was left.

#### Q: Will this make *all* Unity games work properly in Mavericks?

**A**: No. As far as I'm aware, it will allow any Unity 2018/2019 game to start up, but no one said anything about working properly! Games are complex, and these ones have clearly never been tested on Mavericks before, so they may have other glitches. [Timelie](https://www.gog.com/game/timelie) is one example of a game which technically works with this fix, but has very severe graphical problems.

Many other games, however, really do seem to run perfectly.

#### Q: Is it possible to actually reimplement `getattrlistbulk` instead of using a stub function?

**A**: Maybe? The Internet™ says `getattrlistbulk` is a replacement for `getdirentriesattr`. So, at one point I tried:

```
#include <sys/attr.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int getattrlistbulk(int dirfd, struct attrlist * attrList, void * attrBuf, size_t attrBufSize, uint64_t options) {
    
    unsigned int count;
    unsigned int basep;
    unsigned int newState;
    
    return getdirentriesattr(dirfd, &attrList, &attrBuf, attrBufSize, &count, &basep, &newState, options);
}
```

This was written by pattern-matching the example code for `getattrlistbulk` and `getdirentriesattr` in the developer documentation. It does work (insofar as games run), but then, so does `return 0`, so I really have no way to test the code. Under the circumstances, `return 0` seems safer.

#### Q: Can I get a tl;dr?

**A**: Sure:

1. Copy the first code block in this answer into a file named `UnityMavericksWorkarounds.m`.
2. `clang -compatibility_version 9999 -o /Path/To/Game.app/Contents/Frameworks/UnityMavericksWorkarounds.dylib -dynamiclib /Path/To/UnityMavericksWorkarounds.m`
3. `install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/UnityMavericksWorkarounds.dylib /Path/To/Game.app/Contents/Frameworks/UnityPlayer.dylib`
4. Download [optool](https://github.com/alexzielenski/optool).
5. `/Path/To/optool install -c reexport -p /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib -t /Path/To/Game.app/Contents/Frameworks/UnityMavericksWorkarounds.dylib`

Comment: I take my hat off to you for this amazing post on internals for Mavericks - chapeau to a true maverick. There is a [group of people collaborating to make older software work on newer OS](https://github.com/cormiertyshawn895/Retroactive/issues) as well. Both approaches have merits.

Comment: For reference purposes, the source for `getattrlistbulk` as found in OS X 10.10 can be found [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.1.97/bsd/vfs/vfs_attrlist.c.auto.html).

Comment: I have to ask: Why not just upgrade to Yosemite? Apple provides a [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) to download.

Comment: @DavidAnderson And replace this fast, stable, and exquisitely-designed masterpiece with a headache-inducing iOS ripoff? You must be joking good sir!

Comment: Since this question is getting lots of attention—if there's a different way I could have architected this fix, I'd be interested to hear about it. Replacing and re-exporting all of `libsystem` feels hamfisted. Then again, patching someone else's binary is inherently weird, so perhaps it's not surprising that it should lead to weird approaches. I'd also love to know what's _actually_ going on with `getattrlistbulk`—why do games require it, if replacing it with a dumb stub is so effective?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I have to be Sgt. Killjoy and remind the internet that OS X 10.9 is no longer receiving security updates, and yes there has been Mac malware released in the past four years. Even though 10.9 is my favorite OS X too, it is not safe to connect to the internet.

Comment: @Thegs My feeling is that I'm reasonably safe under the circumstances: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23473839 If you have a plausible attack scenario I haven't considered, I'd love to hear about it. Feel free to ping me in chat if it's too much for comments.

Comment: Why doesn't using the `DYLD_INTERPOSE` macro to add the `__DATA,__interpose` section in the binary work? It was my understanding if the `__DATA,__interpose` segment is present then dyld will use that even when two level namespace is in effect. Or does the original symbol first need to exist and be resolved in order for interposing to work?

Comment: @1110101001 "Or does the original symbol first need to exist and be resolved in order for interposing to work?" Yes, exactly, at least from what I can tell—it kept trying to resolve the symbol to interpose it. I need to thank you, though, because it was learning about `DYLD_INTERPOSE` that made me first look into this. I thought (incorrectly, but w/e) that what worked for the Dictionary would also work here. 

Comment: Your list makes me think I'm quite safe on an outdated Windows 7 too. As in, if I avoid visiting any malicious websites and don't run any suspicious looking files, I _should_ be fine, I think?

Comment: @Clockwork I would encourage you to do the analysis for yourself—what are the possible threat scenarios, and what is the consequence of something going wrong? Windows is a bit more dangerous because it's a more common target. But, IMO some people treat all unpatched systems like they're Windows 95 (which really will get hacked if it's connected to the internet for 20 minutes).

Comment: @Wowfunhappy That last statement is what makes me feel uncomfortable. Because I'm just a developer, I don''t know whether or not the simple fact of being plugged makes me vulnerable. Even some questions about Windows XP on Security Stack Exchange seem to mostly mention the risks of using the computer and doing a faux pas.

Comment: @Clockwork: Even the most obsolete and insecure OS can be relatively safe to use if it's behind a firewall that 1) doesn't let any incoming connections through and 2) only allows outgoing connections to specific trusted servers and/or to a trusted proxy that intercepts all data and scans it for potential malware. And which is preferably configured as strictly as possibly, e.g. to block access to any websites not explicitly marked as trusted. But setting up such a firewall in a way that makes the system both secure and usable is far from trivial.