# Is not possible install VirtualBox 7.0.4 in macOS El Capitan

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

For macOS `El Capitan` **10.11.6** was downloaded `VirtualBox` **7.0.4** as *VirtualBox-7.0.4-154605-OSX.dmg*. Was checked/verified the sha256 checksum. When is tried to install it (<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>arrow down</kbd>), appears the following message

[image]

Why appears this? How to fix it? The `.dmg` file was downloaded and verified (checksum) twice and happens the same.

**NOTE** I use VirtualBox 6.1.x (38 as the latest) in peace.

Comment: Documentation says both  6.1.38 and 7.0.4 are not compatible with El Capitan. If you have 6.1.38 working with El Capitan, then consider yourself lucky. Evidently with 7.0.4, your luck has run  out.

Comment: And I just installed 6.1. **40** and works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer DMGs are sometimes not compatible with old versions of macOS. I do not know exactly why or what changed, but as a user of OS X 10.9 Mavericks, I have run into this error before. There is nothing wrong with the DMG, it's just in a format your OS doesn't know how to read.

Try copying the installer out of the DMG in a newer version of macOS, then transferring the files to your El Capitan machine.

VirtualBox may still not work of course, if the app is inherently incompatible with El Capitan. However, it sounds like you're already using a version of VirtualBox which claims to be incompatible, and works anyway, so you might as well keep trying your luck?

Comment: Is there an official link of VirtualBox indicating the minimum requirements? I did do a research and seems there is no one available

Comment: And I just installed 6.1. **40** and works fine

Comment: The "it sounds like" was actually going off what @David Anderson said in the comments above; I don't use VirtualBox, I just knew it was unrelated to the DMG not mounting. Glad to hear it works!

Comment: I'll add—in my experience, it's quite common for legacy macOS compatibility information to be flat-out wrong. I've had apps which claim to work but don't, apps which claim not to work but do, apps which work but are shipped in incompatible DMG files, and just about everything in between.

Comment: Agree - the best teacher is the experience. About `apps which claim not to work but do` I had this situation with `IntelliJ Idea`.

Comment: @ManuelJordan You can do even more fun things with a bit of code. ;) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414688/how-can-i-run-newer-unity-games-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks/414689

Comment: About your link shared - errors similars of that "type" was with Java 17 too - which it does not work in macOS El Capitan.

Comment: Java is open source and so may merely need to be recompiled, with MacPorts's excellent toolchain for supporting legacy OSs. This is on my long-term todo list.

Comment: There is an official post of Eclipse indicating the no support of Java 17 on macOS El Capitan due of the limitations of the OS itself - so I am not sure if macports would do some "magic"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140892/discussion-between-wowfunhappy-and-manuel-jordan).

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox 7 does not list support for OS X 10.11, as per [this article:](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#hostossupport)

macOS hosts (64-bit):

10.15 (Catalina)

11 (Big Sur)

12 (Monterey)

Intel hardware is required. See also Chapter 14, Known Limitations.

An installer package is available for macOS/Arm64, for systems using an Apple silicon CPU. With this package, you can run some guest operating systems for Intel x86/x64 CPUs in an emulation.

The macOS/Arm64 installer package for Apple silicon platform is available as a Developer Preview release. This package represents a work in progress project and the performance is very modest.

VirtualBox 6 does not list support for OS X 10.11, as per [this article:](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/hostossupport.html)

Mac OS X hosts (64-bit):

10.12 (Sierra)

10.13 (High Sierra)

10.14 (Mojave)

Comment: I don't use 6.0.x series - but according with my own use/experience 6.1.x runs in peace in macOS 10.11 - wondered why in the same VirtualBox its documentation is not split for series, it for 6.0.x 6.1.x and 7.0.x

Comment: I updated my answer to indicate that support isn't listed, not that those versions of VB won't work.